# How to avoid stair-stepping with Monad Transformers in scala?

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers, reader-monad

I have the following code that uses the `Reader` monad for configuration and also has to deal with `IO[Option[String]]` and I've ended up with code that stair-steps in my `encode` function.

How can I formulate a monad transformer for `Reader` and `OptionT` to avoid the ugly nested `for` comprehensions in my `encode` function?

```
def encode(fileName: String): Reader[Config, IO[Unit]] = for {
   ffmpegWrapper <- findFfmpegWrapper
   ffmpegBin <- findFfmpeg
} yield (for {
    w <- ffmpegWrapper
    b <- ffmpegBin
    stream <- callFfmpeg(getCommand(w, b, fileName)).liftM[OptionT]
} yield stream) map (_ foreach (println)) getOrElse Unit.box {}


def getCommand(ffmpegWrapper: String, ffmpegBin: String,
             videoFile: String) = s"$ffmpegWrapper $ffmpegBin $videoFile  '-vcodec libx264 -s 1024x576' /tmp/out.mp4"

def callFfmpeg(command: String): IO[Stream[String]] = IO {
  Process(command).lines_!
}

def findFile(path:List[String]): OptionT[IO,String] = OptionT[IO,String](IO{path.find(new File(_).exists)})

def findFfmpeg:Reader[Config, OptionT[IO,String]] = Reader {c=>findFile(c.ffmpegLocations)}

def findFfmpegWrapper:Reader[Config, OptionT[IO,String]] = Reader {c=>findFile(c.ffmpegWrapperLocations)}
```

Thank-you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at the [definition of `Reader` in the Scalaz source](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/ae0489001c5aa129d644f97a9d0fea72c3841e2d/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/package.scala#L115), you'll see this:

```
    type Reader[-E, +A] = ReaderT[Id, E, A]
```

Which tells us that the `Reader` monad you are using is just a specialization of a monad transformer where the monad being wrapped is the trivial `Id` monad. You can use `ReaderT` directly, but wrapping your `OptionT[IO, _]` monad instead of just wrapping everything in a `Reader`. For example, the following should do what you want:

```
type OptionIO[+A] = OptionT[IO, A]

def findFfmpeg: ReaderT[OptionIO, Config, String] =
  Kleisli[OptionIO, Config, String](c => findFile(c.ffmpegLocations))

def findFfmpegWrapper: ReaderT[OptionIO, Config, String] =
  Kleisli[OptionIO, Config, String](c => findFile(c.ffmpegWrapperLocations))

def encode(fileName: String): ReaderT[OptionIO, Config, Unit] = (for {
   w <- findFfmpegWrapper
   b <- findFfmpeg
   stream <- Kleisli[OptionIO, Config, Stream[String]](
     _ => callFfmpeg(getCommand(w, b, fileName)).liftM[OptionT]
   )
} yield stream).map(_ foreach println)
```

In principle you should be able to replace the part after `stream <-` with the following:

```
callFfmpeg(getCommand(w, b, fileName)).liftM[OptionT].liftReaderT[Config]
```

But for some reason the `Unapply` machinery that `liftReaderT` relies on doesn't seem to be working in this case. Writing the `Kleisli` part out explicitly isn't all that horrible, fortunately.

---

As a footnote: the nice `liftReaderT` syntax I mentioned becomes available if you define an `UnapplyCo` instance like this:

```
implicit def unapplyMFA1[TC[_[_]], F[+_], M0[F[+_], +_], A0](
  implicit TC0: TC[({ type L[x] = M0[F, x] })#L]
): UnapplyCo[TC, M0[F, A0]] {
  type M[+X] = M0[F, X]
  type A = A0
} = new UnapplyCo[TC, M0[F, A0]] {
  type M[+X] = M0[F, X]
  type A = A0
  def TC = TC0
  def leibniz = Leibniz.refl
}
```

I'm not sure off the top of my head whether there's a reason Scalaz 7 doesn't currently provide this instance, but it's probably worth looking into.

Comment: I was in the process of writing up a just about identical answer when yours appeared.  I amended the top of your answer with something that was in mine but not in yours about showing the Reader = ReaderT type alias, please feel free to remove it if you think it doesn't add to your answer :)

Comment: @stew: Thanks! I've just added a link to the source you mentioned.

Comment: Travis and @stew this is incredibly helpful!  Just trying it out now.

Comment: Yeah, it works really well.  I think I'm going to have to spend time understanding the unapply mechanics.  This is very much appreciated.

Comment: @cwmyers: The `Unapply` business isn't really intended to be user-facing—it's a trick that's designed to supplement Scala's (fairly weak) type inference. You've run into a gap in the mechanism, and the most reasonable thing to do is probably to skip the nicer syntax, especially since (possibly) upcoming changes will make the issue irrelevant—see the comments [here](https://twitter.com/travisbrown/status/344825492504985604) by Lars Hupel.